# Is $XX^T$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In one of the lectures today, the professor said that if $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ matrix, and the columns of $X$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$, then the matrix $XX^T$ is invertible. I am not sure why this is the case unless $m=n$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $XX^\top v = 0$, then $\|X^\top v\|^2=v^\top XX^\top v=0$, and thus $X^\top v = 0$. Since the rows of $X^\top$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$, we must have $v = 0$, and thus the kernel of $XX^\top$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Can I use the same method on $X^TX$?. If $X^TXv=0$ then $||Xv||^2=v^TX^TXv = 0$ and hence $Xv=0$ but since columns of $X$ span then $v=0$ and so the kernel of $X^TX$ is $\{0\}$??

Comment: I’m not adept in linear algebra, but it fascinates me, so I follow the tag. Is $\left\| X^{\sf T}\right\|$ the magnitude of the determinant of the transpose of matrix $X$?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor $X^T$ is the transpose of $X$, and $||X^Tv||$ is a norm of the vector $X^Tv$ (without other indication, it's usually the euclidian norm, that is $||u||^2=\sum_i u_i^2$).

Comment: @AspiringMat The error in your comment is that "columns of $X$ are spanning" does not allow you to deduce $v = 0$ from $Xv = 0$.

Comment: @angryavian Isn't $Xv$ a linear combination of the columns on $X$? But these columns are linearly independent, so the only way they can add to 0 is if $v$ is 0? I am a bit confused?

Comment: Never mind, I got confused! Thanks

Comment: @AspiringMat Spanning does not mean linearly independent! Consider the matrix $X=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$, for which $X\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The rows of $X^T$ span, so $X^Tv=0$ just when $v=0$, so $XX^Tv=0$ just when $v=0$, so $XX^T$ has kernel $0$, and is square, so is invertible.

Comment: I see. So if $X$ is full rank, then we always have that $XX^T$ and $X^TX$ are both invertible using the same logic you did here, correct?

Comment: No, not both. Try a simple example, like $X=(1 \ 0)$.

Comment: @AspiringMat The columns of $X^T$ may not span

Comment: @angryavian $XX^Tv=0$ implies $v^TXX^Tv=0$ implies $X^Tv=0$